# How to changes the jquery code below to more dynamic code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done the sample jquery code as below. My question is how make it in dynamic code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="deal-mode col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="click-joan" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. Joan</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="click-kelvin" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. Kelvin</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="click-may" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. May</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 wrap-chat-room">
  <div id="chat-joan" class="chat-room">
    <p>Chat With Joan</p>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-kelvin" class="chat-room">
    <p>Chat With Kelvin</p>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-may" class="chat-room">
    <p>Chat With May</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrap-chat-room').css('border', '1px solid red');
  $('#chat-joan').fadeIn();
  $("#click-joan").click(function() {
    //alert(this.id);
    $('#chat-joan').fadeIn();
    $('#chat-kelvin').fadeOut();
    $('#chat-may').fadeOut();
    });

  $("#click-kelvin").click(function() {
    //alert(this.id);
    $('#chat-kelvin').fadeIn();
    $('#chat-joan').fadeOut();
    $('#chat-may').fadeOut();
    });

  $("#click-may").click(function() {
    //alert(this.id);
    $('#chat-may').fadeIn();
    $('#chat-kelvin').fadeOut();
    $('#chat-joan').fadeOut();
    });


});
```

**CSS:**

```
.row { padding: 0 2%; }
.col-md-6 { width: 46%; padding: 2%; float: left; }
.chat-room { display: none; }
```

Here is the [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/z8jj2ej2/1/)

Any solution or idea are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Add the click events to the panel div instead of to the individual rooms.

Comment: Do you have any example to refer? Thanks.

Comment: common class, hide those and show the active one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example to get started. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8jj2ej2/2/)

**Note:** I have added `class="click"` to all 3 `<a>` and used it as the jQuery selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrap-chat-room').css('border', '1px solid red');
  $('#chat-joan').fadeIn();

  $(".click").click(function() {
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('click', 'chat');
    $('[id^=chat]').fadeOut();
    $(id).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 0 2%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  width: 46%;
  padding: 2%;
  float: left;
}

.chat-room {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="deal-mode col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="click" id="click-joan" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. Joan</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="click" id="click-kelvin" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. Kelvin</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="click" id="click-may" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. May</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 wrap-chat-room">
    <div id="chat-joan" class="chat-room">
      <p>Chat With Joan</p>
    </div>
    <div id="chat-kelvin" class="chat-room">
      <p>Chat With Kelvin</p>
    </div>
    <div id="chat-may" class="chat-room">
      <p>Chat With May</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pugazh thanks for the help. Yes, you solve my problem:)

Comment: @JoeltonDingYingChor : Welcome, Happy to Help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes and data attributes

```js
$('[data-toggles]').on('click', function() {
  var show = $(this).data('toggles');
  $(show).stop().fadeIn();
  $('.items').not(show).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggles="#d1">One</button>
<button data-toggles="#d2">Two</button>
<button data-toggles="#d3">Three</button>

<div id="d1" class="items">One</div>
<div id="d2" class="items">Two</div>
<div id="d3" class="items">Three</div>
```